# How to handle divergences in Poisson's equation in the presence of a point charge?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, mathematics, singularities

I'm looking for a (fairly) mathematically-rigorous resolution to the following). Suppose an electron is moving through an electric field in some region: $$\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d \ ,$$ where $d = 2,3$. We know that the electron - as a charged particle - will experience a force from this field. We also know that the electron will change the ambient field, as it moves through space. If: $$\mathbf{x}_a(t)$$ represents the position of the electron at time, $t$, the equations governing this interaction are the following:

\begin{align}-\epsilon_0\nabla^2 \Phi &= e\delta(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_a(t)) \ , \tag{1}
\\[1em]
\dot{\mathbf{v}} &= \frac{e\nabla \Phi}{m} \ , \tag{2}
\end{align}

where $\Phi$ is the electric potential at $\mathbf{x} \in \Omega$.

Since, the source term in (1) is a [Dirac Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), the electric potential $\Phi$ will have a singularity at $\mathbf{x}_a(t)$.

However, if this is the case, $\nabla \Phi$ is a meaningless expression.

How is this resolved?

Unrelated, but if one wanted to simulate such an interaction, how would one contend with the singularity in $\Phi$ at $\mathbf{x}_a(t)$ ?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151109/discussion-on-question-by-zachary-candelaria-mathematically-ill-posed-problem); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: OP there have been long discussions and responses to your question. If none of them solves the issue please consider providing more details. You can also comment on solutions you do not understand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is mathematically no problem with differentiating distributions like the $\delta$-distribution, you just need to use the notion of the [distributional (or weak) derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributional_derivative). The particular case of solving a differential equation
$$ Df = \delta$$
with $D$ some linear differential operator is the theory of [Green's functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function).

Comment: I think OP knows this (I hope), but OP problem is not necessarily about taking the derivative, it seems to be about  evaluating the expression at the particle's position.

Comment: @Mauricio The question as written states that the problem is that $\nabla f$ is ill-defined when $f$ is singular at some points. The distributional derivative is the resolution of this problem. If OP already knew this, then the question is badly written, but I see no reason to assume this.

Comment: How is this a resolution? The question is about problem in the equation of motion, total potential $\Phi$ and its gradient are not defined at the position of the particle. One may complete the definition at the point of the particle ad hoc based on the observed motion, but then the model is useless, it does not relate this completion value to anything known.

Comment: @JánLalinský You have to understand $\Phi$, a solution to the differential equation above, as a distribution.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I do, but that is not what the question is about! Even with $\Phi$ as distribution defined by (1), the equation (2) is nonsensical, because although $\nabla \Phi$ is a fine distribution, (2)refers to value of $\nabla \Phi$ at the position of the particle, and this is not a meaningful things for distributions singular at that position.

Answer (score 12):

Besides taking the electron to be a small ball of radius $r$ (and taking the limit $r\to 0$ if necessary after calculating the force), the other simple approach is to just not include the potential due to the electron itself in the force calculation. This is usually done implicitly when using Coulomb's law to calculate the force on a point charge. Mathematically, we can write
$$m\dot{\mathbf v}=e\mathbf\nabla\left[\Phi+\frac{e}{4\pi\epsilon_0|\mathbf x-\mathbf x_a(t)|}\right]$$
where I've assumed $e>0$. The second term in brackets is the negative of the potential due to the electron. This is more useful if the electron isn't the only charge contributing to $\Phi$.

Finally, for a more precise treatment one must use the complete set of Maxwell's equations without ignoring the magnetic field and radiation. For example, a [self-force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force) is exerted on accelerating charges.

Comment: Self-force is for extended charge distributions. Point particle models were never extended successfully with self-force or the LAD-force ideas. The idea of self-force/radiation reaction force does not work consistently for point particles, only for systems of such particles, or for continuous charge distributions. The LAD force is an approximation, just one term in an infinite series expressing net EM force on a quasi-rigid ball/sphere of charge in general motion.

Answer (score 7):

The mathematics is very clear, there is a singularity, the equation diverges at the particle position.

However in physics, these kind of singularities are not a problem because they serve as effective models up to a certain level of precision. In this case, the equation is showing us that if we treat the particle as a classical point the model fails "close" to the particle, meaning there is a length scale at which this approximation is valid and further down it breaks down. One could for example, consider that the electron has a radius, this modification could solve the problem. The process is called [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(physics)). For charged elementary particles, this whole issue leads to [quantum electrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics) in which the equations become more complicated.

Comment: The model fails at any distance from the particle. A simple example is the Lamb shift.

Comment: @JQK up to a certain level of precision.

Comment: The point of a mathematical model is to compute quantitative results. So, obviously precision is important.

Comment: Either you choose physics or mathematics but you cannot choose both. In physics these models works great up to a certain precision, if not we would have discovered problems with classical mechanics much earlier.

Comment: Also, OP seems to be asking a question about functions from real numbers to real numbers. The solution is not to tell OP to instead consider functions from real numbers to quantum operators. That is not a solution to OP question, as I understand it.

Comment: @hft as I see it there are three problems here and OP stopped responding to have some feedback. 1) How to handle the derivatives of distributions like that? 2) How to handle the singularity? (I think this is a physics question or simply you dont) 3) how do we simulate a particle like that if it has a singularity? (last question of OP)

Comment: For (3) see the answer of Puk.

Comment: @Mauricio I think all three are effectively math questions in physics clothing.

Comment: @hft you can regularize without calling for quantum operators. Just define a radius and then replace the electron by a uniformly charged sphere with that radius for example.

Answer (score 4):

Singularities are mathematical models of "small"-dimensional features. They provide information of what happens outside them.

If your problem is to evaluate the force on a point particle, you could exclude the self-contribution of the particle to the electric field.
You can prove that the force on a point charge doesn't depend on the electric field produced by that particle (or at least it could be a reasonable approximation) using regularization.

As an example, the regularization with uniform charge distribution reads
[image]

With this regularization, the force acting on a particle reads
[image]

Comment: There is no need to make the charges point like. Forces between charged spheres are perfectly well defined. We even teach electrostatics that way in school. As long as the spheres are small compared to their distance everything is fine. Somehow Gauss seems to mess this up in people's minds. Suddenly small is "not good enough" anymore and we are developing an unhealthy obsession with the infinitesimal.

Comment: I agree. The most important things of my answer is that OP could exclude the contribution of charge $k$ to the electric field when he wants to evaluate force on $k$, and I provided a "proof", since no other answers have provided one before

Comment: BTW, one could only say: could a body produce a net force on itself?

Comment: @FlatterMann forces on charged sphere are defined in electrostatics. As soon as the charged bodies accelerate, things become difficult because sphere or any extended object has infinite number of state variables. Point particle has only six.

Comment: @JánLalinský The ontology of a theory doesn't depend on the difficulty to calculate a particular result. One should however not mistake the failure of approximations for a failure of the theory. One has nothing to do with the other. Classical electrodynamics is perfectly well defined for test charges, which are assumed not to radiate. They shouldn't be mistaken for real charge distributions which do. That we prefer to leave it to the engineers to model hard electrodynamics calculations numerically is yet another affair.

Comment: @FlatterMann There is no need to assume test charges do not radiate. The radiation of electron/proton implied by Maxwell's equations is so weak it does not cause any problems to their function as a test charge. There are many theories, some do not have point charges, some do.

Comment: @JánLalinský That is true. Nature provides us with useful electromagnetic test charges. I am not sure the folks who are doing QCD are quite as lucky. I never thought about it that way.

Comment: glad, if it's been useful

Answer (score 4):

> Suppose an electron is moving through an electric field in some region...
>
> We know that the electron - as a charged particle - will experience a force from this field.

Yes, but stop here for a second. The field you are referring to, the field which produces a force on your electron, is **external** to the electron. It is not sourced by the electron itself, but rather is sourced by some other external charges (and if there are no *other* charges anywhere then there is no external field and the electron does not experience any force).

> We also know that the electron will change the ambient field, as it moves through space.

Yes, but again, the electron can act on all the *other* charges and all the *other* charges can act on the electron, but the electron can not act on itself.

> If: $$\mathbf{x}_a(t)$$ represents the position of the electron at time, $t$, the equations governing this interaction are the following:

Your equations that I'm quoting below are wrong (or else the description of the problem, or my interpretation of it is wrong). There is clearly a conventional sign error, but there are also *physics* errors. Namely, you are forgetting about external field that you already postulated to be acting on the electron and by which the electron is "experienc[ing] a force."

> $$-\epsilon_0\nabla^2 \Phi = e\delta(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_a(t)) \ , \tag{1}
> $$

The above equation is wrong. The $\Phi$ field is not sourced by just the electron, so there should be other terms:
$$
-\epsilon_0\nabla^2 \Phi = e\delta(\vec{x} - \vec{x}_a(t)) +\rho_{\text{everything else}}(\vec x, t) \ , \tag{1'}
$$

> $$
> \dot{\mathbf{v}} = \frac{e\nabla \Phi}{m} \ , \tag{2}
> $$

The above equation has a sign error and it should not include the self-field. It should read:
$$
\dot{\mathbf{v}} = -\frac{e\nabla \Phi_e}{m}  \tag{2'}\;,
$$
where
$$
-\epsilon_0\nabla^2 \Phi_e = \rho_{\text{everything else}}(\vec x, t) \ , \tag{1}
$$

Comment: Maybe everything else is far away (uniform static field)

Comment: @Mauricio It doesn't matter. OP says there is a force on the electron, so there has to be other charge somewhere. The electron can not act on itself, that is just a mistake based on confusion introduced by the field concept; i.e., the concept that there is some field $\vec E(\vec x)$ that has a value everywhere in space and the force on a charge at a location $\vec z$ is $q\vec E(\vec z)$.

Comment: This is correct mathematical resolution of the problem, but has needlessly aggressive tone. Yes, people have the misconception that $\Phi$ (or $\mathbf E$) in the equation of motion (2) is the total field (sum of all contributions); but this misunderstanding is quite common.

Comment: @JánLalinský Aggressive tone? You mean because I use the word "No" twice? OK, I'll remove it and you tell me if it reads nicer.

Comment: I guess I need to work on being nicer...

Comment: It read a little aggressive/not nice. Telling someone all they've written is wrong... Sometimes that needs to be said, but I don't think the question calls for that. Maybe I'm wrong, take with some salt.

Comment: @JánLalinský Yeah, you are right, the question is not that bad. There are definitely worse ones out there.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly it isn't resolved. The mathematical rabbit hole here is very deep, and poorly connected to real physics. The Euclidean point is not always a good model for an electron.

Comment: Whether or not this is a "good model" is an opinion, but stating this "isn't resolved" is just wrong. The theory of distributional solutions and weak derivatives is a well-established part of mathematics. This *particular* case of solving an equation with a $\delta$-function as source is especially standard as the theory of Green's functions/fundamental solutions.

Comment: @ACuriousMind That's a deep mathematical rabbit hole poorly connected to real physics. So, we mostly don't worry about it: no experimental result depends on it.

Comment: The question asks how to treat the model of the point particle correctly in mathematical terms; it does not ask for our opinion of the physical relevance of this model.

Comment: The ontology of "test particle" is quite well defined in classical physics. The charge is assumed to be so small that it does not change anything significant about the sources of the field that it probes (i.e. changes to the boundary conditions are negligible). It also does not have to be a point charge. Indeed, in high school we demonstrate electrostatics exclusively with macroscopic charge distributions. There are, unfortunately, many standard textbooks that make lazy approximations in their exercise sections that blur the ontology. I am looking at you, Jackson.

Comment: @FlatterMann And sensible physicists don't worry about ontology. We worry about how well the properties of our completely imaginary mathematical objects map to the properties of the real systems we model. Use an imaginary point particle's properties to the extent that they fit the physical situation, while avoiding reasoning from its unphysical properties.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Then it isn't a physics question and belongs in math.se.

Comment: A sensible educator does worry about teaching their students a proper understanding of theories. This is an educational site, after all. At least this is my understanding. I do agree about the math. The naive mathematical treatment of field theories leads to problems, but they are math problems, not physics problems.

Comment: @FlatterMann Yes, and the proper understanding is "all models are wrong, but some models are useful". Obsessing on the wrong parts is not sensible.

Comment: That's why classical electrodynamics does not obsess about point charges. It has no use for them. It's not a theory of matter, after all. (Not that point charges work in the proper theory of matter, either.).

Comment: @FlatterMann Yet if you're steering electron beams around using fields, it's all classical electrodynamics applied to particles. You just avoid worrying about the electron's interaction with its own field: it may be mathematically intractable, but it has no real effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151094/discussion-between-flattermann-and-john-doty).

Answer (score 1):

Maxwell's equations are valid everywhere except at charges.  There's a long history of this problem the culminates in quantum electrodynamics (QED) that includes the self-energy of the electron.    QED requires a substantial update to your very simple model.   Before QED, various folks would model the electron as a sphere with a radius, but all these efforts fall apart very quickly.

Comment: There are no "charges" in Maxwell's equations. There are only charge distributions. QED can't calculate the self-energy of the electron, either. The concept does not even make sense in QFT. Self-energy (mass) is scale dependent. Working with spheres in classical electromagnetism is perfectly valid. That's how we teach physics in high school. Somewhere along the way (probably when students encounter Gauss) people take on poor mental habits of trying to reduce things to mathematical points. That is not what Gauss says, though.

Comment: Maxwell's equations are valid at charged as well, even point charges - mathematically delta distributions work fine as sources in Maxwell's equations.

Comment: The first comment says there are no charges, and the second comment says there are charges.  These comments sum to zero.

Comment: @JQK The whole is certainly greater than the sum of its parts here. Jan Lalinsky is right and so am I. He certainly pointed out the correct approach: "delta distributions" are not objects. They can be understood as limits in certain function spaces and they are the mathematician's equivalent of "test charges". It is all well defined from a mathematical point of view. Since I am an experimentalist, though, I have to keep pointing out that nature does not appreciate functional analysis that much. She doesn't go there. Instead she quantizes the field, which is an entirely different animal.